# devcon.exe not working in Windows7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I can't use the ia64-version of [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/EN-US) on my Windows7 professional x64 (AMD CPU). 
error message tells me, that the version of this applcation is not suitable for this version of windows and I should check whether I need to use a x64 or x86 version of this application.

The x86 version starts correctly, but all operations (remove, restart, disable etc) fail. 
Running from a command line with full privileges.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although there is no x64 version in the package provided [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/EN-US), there is one in the [WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff).

Instructions on how to get the x64 out of the WDK can be found [here](http://www.techlikes.com/2010/09/25/devcon-problem-in-windows-7-solved.html)

Main page for WDK can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428)

Comment: The MS download is an .iso. In the ISO, devcon is inside a .cab archive: wdk\setuptools_x64fre_cab001.cab. The file is named "_devcon.exe_00000", so you probably want to rename it to devcon.exe.

Answer (score 4):

That is for the [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium) architecture. Just because Itanium is 64-bit, it is VERY different from the 64-bit Windows OS'es you see here day to day. It requires a different set of chips and a different type of processor. It will not work.

Also, based according to [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272/EN-US), it was not designed for Windows 7.

Comment: I know the difference between IA64 and x64. However in the separate package provided by MS there was no x64 version. However, in the WDK there is one and it works. Thanks though

Comment: You might post a link to that location to help others.

Comment: I just did. see my answer.